# C++ winapi: How to transform current time into a string?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

I want to convert the current time into a string to later display it using the Drawtext function in WM_PAINT. Format hh:mm:ss.

And what is the most convenient way of getting the time to later turn it into a string.

Comment: in what problem call [`GetSystemTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`GetLocalTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use `swprinf` for format. `gdi` here at all unrelated

Comment: I guess I didn't specify it correctly, in the end my goal is to display the time using the gdi Drawtext.

Comment: `DrawText` display string. content of string - absolute not important

Comment: You need to learn how to break a problem down into parts. There is no function that draws time. There exist functions to draw strings, and functions to convert time to strings. Call one after the other and the job is done.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to format a time string.

If you want a specific format you can format the string yourself:

```
WCHAR buf[100];
SYSTEMTIME st;
GetLocalTime(&st); // Local time
wsprintfW(buf, L"%.2u:%.2u:%.2u", st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond); // 24h format
DrawTextW(hDC, buf, -1, &yourRect, DT_LEFT);
```

If you want to format the time using the users preferences then you must call [`GetTimeFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318130(v=vs.85).aspx) instead. Or you could use the [C standard library functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4ddyt9h.aspx).

When you get a `WM_PAINT` message you call `BeginPaint` and `GetClientRect`, then `DrawText` and finally `EndPaint`.

Comment: error C4995: 'wsprintfW': name was marked as #pragma deprecated

Comment: @PavelVlasov There is no security issue here, the input will never overflow this buffer. Consult your toolchains documentation to figure out how to turn off this warning or switch to something like _snwprintf.